# Facebook iOS SDK FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATH

Tags: ios, ipad, warnings, xcode4.5, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using Facebook iOS SDK 3.5 in my ipad App. I added framework, setup everything and everything is working fine. But when I copied my project source code to some other place other than where it is currently and build the project again, I get an XCode Apple Mach-O Linker Warning as directory not found `[CURRENT_APPLICATION_PATH]/../../FacebookSDK.`
After searching for sometime, I found out that in XCode Build Settings, `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` has a path as `"$(SRCROOT)/../../FacebookSDK"` which is what I think is the cause for that warning. If I remove that, I am getting error messages at all `#import <FacebookSDK/FaceSDK.h>` statements. 
So obviously, I need that above mentioned `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS.` But how would I get rid of that Xcode warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to your faceBook SDK missing error. Solution for this problem is that delete facebook sdk from your project and re add it. Remember that When you add faceBook SDK in your project tick copy checkbox inside "**Choose option for adding these file**" popup window which add facebook sdk permanently for your project.

OR

if it is showing just warning at compile time then you can follow this procedure too

1.> go to your project-xcode ,right click , show in finder, yourProjectName.xcodeproj would show

2.> now right click on yourProjectName.xcodeproj and go show package contents, choose and open project.pbxproj file into textEditor and serach facebook and delete following lines. and save and compile

```
"\"$(SRCROOT)/../../../Documents/FacebookSDK\"",
"\"$(SRCROOT)/../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK\"",
"\"$(SRCROOT)/../../../../../Downloads/SKYPE/Sproutt BACKUP/FacebookSDK\"",
"\"$(SRCROOT)/../../../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK\"",
"\"$(SRCROOT)/../../../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK 3\"",
"\"$(SRCROOT)/../../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK\"",
```

**NOTE :-**  Don't quit textEditor until you make all changes because if any problem occur then you can UNDO your changes.

I hope it work. Please let me know if any problem you would have face. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply chandan. I tried that and still I am out of luck. Any other suggestion that you can think of would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome @Murali. If it is just a warning then please neglect it. Or if it is an error then delete facebook sdk , clear xcode, quit xcode , restart xcode , clear xcode, then follow my answer . Please let me know if any problem still occurring.

Comment: Hi @Murali i have edited my answer and add some more way to cope up from this problem. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Chandan. It is all good and working now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply do `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` and it will work for any user cloning your project and storing FacebookSDK in his Documents folder