# Adding the sdwebImage framework to the projectes show Apple Mac-O linker error?

Tags: ios, linker-errors, sdwebimage, linker-warning

in my projects when i tried to add the sdWebImage Framework show the Mac-O linker Error

the error is

```
 directory not found for option '-F/Users/9Atoms/Desktop/Alfred Consumer/October/Alfred-21/Alfred_Waiter/../../../../Documents/FacebookSDK'

 duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SDImageCache in:
/Users/9Atoms/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlfredWaiter-ervnyccnggvruvcubcrgzmkhvymj/Build/Intermediates/AlfredWaiter.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlfredWaiter.build/Objects-normal/i386/SDImageCache.o

/Users/9Atoms/Desktop/Alfred Consumer/October/Alfred-21/Alfred_Waiter/SDWebImage.framework/SDWebImage(SDImageCache.o)


linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I cleaned my project
I deleted all values in my Target -> Build Settings -> Library Search Paths and Header SearchPaths
I looked onto my project.pbxproj  but still same error

Comment: linker errors have to deal with imports, not cleaning/building, you are missing a framework buddy :3 most likly CFNetworking

Comment: Oh it says duplicate symbol.. you may have already imported something or imported the .m file instead of .h

Comment: I have't imported any .m file just i have added sdWebImage Framework to the bundle it shows the mac error

Comment: check to see if your project builds with out importing SDWebImage into any of your classes, then #import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h" for downloading images,

Comment: Yeah i have added CFNetworking FramekWork

Comment: oh... did you import any other frameworks that use SDWebImage ?

Comment: I have imported "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h" but still it say same eroor

Comment: directory not found for option ../../FacebookSDK  that seems weird too, you didn't override the directory of FacebookSDK with your SDWebImage directory right ?

Comment: SDWebImage,facebookSDk,MapKit,GoogleOpenSource,GooglePlus,AssestsLibrary,CoreLocation,CoreMotion,CoreText,MediaPlayer,Security,AudioToolBox,MobileCoreServices,SystemCOnfiguration,CFNetwork,Libz,QuartyCore,Uikit,Foundation,CoreGraphits i am using all this FrameWorks

Comment: @A'sa Dickens i did't get wht r u asking ?

Comment: 4 of those are frameworks not given to you by apple ?

Comment: yes SDWEbImage,Facebook,Google Frame Works are not given by apple

Comment: none of those use SDWebImage ?

Comment: yes none those uses SDWebImage framework

Comment: bleh >.< linker errors. ... so vague yet need such simple fixes XD.... there's probably some wenderlich tutorial about linker errors... try making a new project with just sdwebimage, and see if it works

Comment: I am adding SDwebImage Framework but why its showing error FaceBook dir Not found

Comment: Finally i am able to remove that dir not found for facebook uisng <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434394/facebook-ios-sdk-framework-search-path> but not able to remove linker error for SDWebImage Framework

Comment: add ImageIO.framework to your project

Comment: yeah i have  added that frame work too but still same problem

Comment: ld: 36 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) still i am getting the same error

Comment: you have two of the same framework added ? or maybe you imported a file twice.... make sure you only import the SDWebImage and not the entire unzipped file that comes with the tutorial

Comment: I check it. i have not added twice SDWebImages framework

Answer (score 0):

if you have 
    #import <SDWebImage-3.3/UIImageView+WebCache.h> 
change it for
    #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

Comment: #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>  Iam using this only

Comment: do you have a framework called "SDWebImage-3.3.framework"?
the import name and the framework name need to have the same name.
/
 ->nameProject
     ->SDWebImage.framework
       ->Headers
         ->UIImageView+WebCache.h

inside the class ViewController.m
   #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
try without special characters or download the framework from here: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/releases